# CakePHP 3 - Users belongsToMany Users

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.0

I have a specific request, to build an association between users. This causes me confusion, how to reduce duplicate associations, query and results?

The starting point would look like this?

```
// UsersTable
$this->belongsToMany('Users', [
            'through' => 'Connections',
        ]);
```

How to fetch all associations in one query, regardless of whether users key in "user_from" or "user_to" field?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using aliases?

Your `users` table:

```
class UsersTable extends Table 
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('ToConnections', [
            'className' => 'Connections',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_to'
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('FromConnections', [
            'className' => 'Connections',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_from'
        ]);

    }
}
```

And your `connections` table:

```
class ConnectionsTable extends Table 
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('ToUsers', [
            'className' => 'Users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_to'
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('FromUsers', [
            'className' => 'Users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_from'
        ]);

    }
}
```

You can then use `contain()` to load associated models as required.

```
$query = $conections->find()->contain([
    'ToUsers',
    'FromUsers'
]);

$recipients = TableRegistry::get('users');
$query = $recipients->find()->contain([
    'ToConnections.FromUsers',
]);
```

Comment: Correct, using aliases for your relationships would be the best use case here.

Comment: I thought about that approach. But this give us two associations. Results should be sorted for example, by date

Comment: @Salines `$connections->find()` should allow you to search by `date`, `user_from` or `user_to`.

Comment: As it's a `belongsTo` association, you can even search by fields such as `ToUsers.email` or `FromUsers.role`.