# Self-referencing Association via Matching Table CakePHP3

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, cakephp-3.0

I've a table with institutions. Now I want to match two of them via matching table (one institution can hold another). Because this is a many-to-many relation (I guess) I need a JOIN with matching_table and a second JOIN with the original table.

```
SELECT
i.id, i.inst_name, i.inst_name
FROM
institution i
JOIN
matching_table m ON i.id = m.foo_id
JOIN
institution i2 ON m.bar_id = i2.id
WHERE
i.id = 42
```

What is the best way to describe this issue in CakePHP3 ?

I tried

```
        $this->belongsToMany('Institutions', [
        'through' => 'matching_table',
        'foreignKey' => 'i2'
    ]);
```

in my Institutions Table without success. The SQL seems right. I get two query results with the correct amount of rows but If I try this I get an empty Entity...

```
        $institutions = $this->Institutions->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Institutions']
    ]);
```

Comment: If you want to create a self-referencing association, then you need to choose unique aliases, associating `Institutions` with `Institutions` most likely won't work properly (if at all).

Comment: Using aliases is the way forward, as suggested by @ndm. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491449/cakephp-3-users-belongstomany-users/34494619#34494619