# CakePHP 3 - Save Users hasMany Users

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.0

This is actually the continuation of
[CakePHP 3 - Users belongsToMany Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491449/cakephp-3-users-belongstomany-users)

I don't know how to implement the save procedure correctly.

Instead of users I have institutions. One institution can be annexed by another. So I need a self-referencing model.

I'd like to use a dropdown menu to add (or remove) annexed institutions, like so:

[image: Mockup Screenshot]

This is what I have so far:

**InstitutionsTable.php**

```
        $this->hasMany('ConnectionsTo', [
        'className' => 'Connections',
        'foreignKey' => 'institution_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('ConnectionsFrom', [
        'className' => 'Connections',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    ]);
```

**ConnectionsTable.php**

```
        $this->belongsTo('InstitutionsTo', [
        'className' => 'Institutions',
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->belongsTo('InstitutionsFrom', [
        'className' => 'Institutions',
        'foreignKey' => 'institution_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

**InstitutionsController.php**

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $institutions = $this->Institutions->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['ConnectionsFrom.InstitutionsFrom','ConnectionsTo.InstitutionsTo']
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $institutions = $this->Institutions->patchEntity($institutions, $this->request->getData(),[
        'associated' => ['ConnectionsFrom.InstitutionsFrom','ConnectionsTo.InstitutionsTo']
        ]);
        if ($this->Institutions->save($institutions)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The institution has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The institution could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $instList = $this->Institutions->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('institutions', 'instList'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['institutions']);
}
```

**Partial Debug of $this->request->getData()**

Note: This is the property where the value of the control/select is saved.

```
'ConnectionsFrom' => [
    'InstitutionsFrom' => '1'
],
...
```

**Partial Debug of $institutions**

Note: This is the property which is loaded via 'contain'. I've added some entries manually in the DB to test the correct implementation.

```
'connections_from' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Connection) {

        'id' => (int) 42,
        'institution_id' => (int) 17,
        'institutions_from' => object(App\Model\Entity\Institution) {

            'id' => (int) 17,
            ...
```

**edit.ctp**

```
echo $this->Form->control('ConnectionsFrom.InstitutionsFrom',['options' => $instList]);
```

The **main problem** is:

I have a property in which I can save all the institution IDs from the dropdown values. But I have a *second* property which holds Objects of the type App\Model\Entity\Institution and I don't know how to merge them. I (or Cake) have to save an object of type "Connection" not an integer value from the dropdown into this property.

Right now, I use query()->update() as a workaround to write into the database directly. But I want it the Cake way. So, what do I have to tell Cake to save/patch correctly?

Comment: Have you got an association between Users and ToConnections?

Comment: Yes, I've used the set-up as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491449/cakephp-3-users-belongstomany-users

Comment: As originally stated there, or did you change it per the suggestion? Putting your current code here would help, I think.

Comment: I've added far more details now... hope this helps